# Which option do I select for Security Group Source?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-vpc

I am developing my Security Group for a VPC that has my Elasticbeanstalk, RDS and ElastiCache services and I am at this dashboard:

[image]

Under **Source**, it used to be that you could select `sg-0x12345-my-application`, but now it only gives you the option of **Custom**, **Anywhere** or **MyIP** and I am not sure which one is the equivalent to selecting the security group for the architecture I am building this SG for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use **Custom** and then start typing `sg-...` and it should pop up a list of available groups.

Comment: Hey there, as you were providing the answer I was answering my own question as well, but I will go ahead and select yours as the answer and delete mine.

Comment: By the way, it didn't pop up a list of available `sg-...,` I just had to copy and paste it in the input field to the right of Custom.